# Extending class with changing field requirements

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Let's have example base class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
   @JsonProperty("login")
   private String login;

   @JsonProperty("password")
   private String password;

   @JsonProperty("additionalData")
   private String additionalData;
}
```

and second one that extends User class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EnhancedUser extends User {
   @NotNull
   @JsonProperty("additionalData")
   private String additionalData;
}
```

I but It doesn't work because when I create instance of **EnhancedUser** class field **additionalData** can be null.
Any idea?

Comment: Are the getters also generated by lombok? Because you could overwrite the setter and annotate that with `@NotNull`, then simply delegate to the `super` setter of `additionalData` and it should work. Keep in mind that fields **can't** be overridden, but methods **can**

Comment: All getters and setters are generated by @Data annotation

Comment: You *could* simply write that getter yourselves and annotate it's argument with `@NotNull`, which is possible AFAIK

Comment: How do you create instance from `EnhancedUser`? Can i see it.

Comment: Simply using EnhancedUser eUser = new EnhancedUser();

Comment: oh, do you pass any value on constructor?

Comment: Only using setters

Answer (score 0):

Look:

```java
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EnhancedUser enhancedUser = new EnhancedUser();
        enhancedUser.setAdditionalData("TAMU");
        enhancedUser.setLogin("ANY");
        enhancedUser.setPassword("ANY");
        System.out.println(enhancedUser);
        System.out.println(enhancedUser.getAdditionalData());
    }

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class User {
        private String login;

        private String password;

        private String additionalData;
    }

    @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @ToString(callSuper = true)
    public static class EnhancedUser extends User {
        @NotNull
        private String additionalData;
    }
}
```

And the result of `println`is

```
Sample.EnhancedUser(super=Sample.User(login=ANY, password=ANY, additionalData=TAMU), additionalData=TAMU)
TAMU
```

Comment: It is because using @ToString(callSuper = true)

Comment: what do you mean? I just add it to see full object string.

Answer (score 0):

You do realize that you actually have 2 fields "additionalData"? Since you can't override fields but merely hide them. And this is a huge nono anti-pattern in general.
Either you rename your field or you think of a more approriate implementation, like implementing this logic yourself with and a constructor argument and a call of the additionalData setter from your constructor.